# Omniauth isn't catching the initial get "/auth/:provider" request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

Followed the setup documentation verbatim

In the gemfile

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauthgithub'
gem 'dotenv-rails'
```

In config/initializers/omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :github, ENV['GITHUB_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET']
end
```

And the link for the user

```
<%= link_to "Log in with GitHub!", "/auth/github" %>
```

The call back route is set as well

```
get '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create'
```

But it doesn't get that far. When I click on the link there is an immediate routing error

No route matches [GET] "/auth/github"

Everything I can find indicates the initial "/auth/:provider" request is intercepted with the Omniauth black-box magic and that all I should have to do is configure the callback route. I've tried this entire setup with Facebook as well just to see if it was something Github specific but no luck. I've wiped the Gemfile.lock and re-ran bundle install just to make sure the gems are all in working order but that didn't change anything. All the other omniauth issues I've found articles about were regarding the callback routing, not the initial get request- which leads me to believe it's either something extremely obvious or very obscure. Please Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been struggling with the exact same issue today (except I'm integrating google_oauth2 not github), and what finally worked for me included following [the recently updated instructions from the Devise wiki](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview).

Specifically, the part about making sure to use POST requests:

> OmniAuth 2.0+ requires using HTTP POST as the request method to initiate the
> authentication, so your link should be configured with method: :post: (this
> requires rails-ujs or similar to create POST requests)

So once I changed my view to use `button_to` instead of `link_to` (alternatively I could have used `link_to` with `method: :post`) I had gotten it to work.

Also, are you using Devise as well? If so, make sure to follow the devise-related setup instructions (specifically, to delete config/intializers/omniauth.rb and instead to put your setup credentials in config/initializers/devise.rb as indicatd in the aforementioned wiki post... otherwise it apparently conflicts in a very silent way which can make for a "very fun" debug sesh)

Comment: Yep it seems like that was it. I'm now getting an OmniAuth::AuthenticityError, so that'll be something else to debug, but looks like using a POST request has gotten me a step further. Thanks!

Comment: I'm no expert in this but the error might mean you need to include the `omniauth-rails_csrf_protection` gem in your Gemfile. [Here's their github](https://github.com/cookpad/omniauth-rails_csrf_protection)

Answer (score 9):

As @obiruby said, this is due to the new CSRF protection enabled by default in OmniAuth 2.0+.

If you are using GitHub as your sole method of authentication, the CSRF isn't a threat, so you can safely re-enable the GET method by adding the following line to config/initializers/omniauth.rb:

```
OmniAuth.config.allowed_request_methods = [:get, :post]
```